# Custom sort in xml file and coloring table rows

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Hi everyone i have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="10_schedule.xsl"?>
  <Schedule> 
    <Lesson>
            <Title>Artificial Intelligence</Title>
            <Lecture Classroom="BA">
                <Day>Wednesday</Day>
                <Time>09-11</Time>
            </Lecture>
            <Lecture Classroom="BA">
                <Day>Thursday</Day>
                <Time>09-11</Time>
            </Lecture>
            <Professor>Peter</Professor>
    </Lesson>
    <Lesson>
            <Title>Constraint Satisfaction Problems</Title>
            <Lecture Classroom="B3">
                <Day>Monday</Day>
                <Time>19-21</Time>
            </Lecture>
    </Lesson>       
    <Lesson>
            <Title>Knowledge Representation in Web</Title>
            <Lecture Classroom="P200">
                <Day>Friday</Day>
                <Time>15-17</Time>
            </Lecture>
            <Professor>David</Professor>
    </Lesson>
```

and this XSL file:

```
  enter code here<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
    <body>
        <h2>Schedule</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#888888">
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Professor</th>
                    <th>Day</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Schedule/Lesson/Lecture">
                    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="string-length(substringbefore('|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|',@Day))"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../Title" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../Professor"/>
                        </td>
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="Day = 'Monday' " >
                                <td bgcolor="#7d78fc">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Professor"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:when> 
                            <xsl:when test="Day = 'Tuesday' ">
                                <td bgcolor="#f6fc78">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Professor"/>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Title"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:when>                                 
                            <xsl:when test="Day = 'Wednesday' ">
                                <td bgcolor="#990033">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Professor"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="Day = 'Friday' ">
                                <td bgcolor="#00ccff">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Professor"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="Day = 'Thursday' ">
                                <td bgcolor="#ccccff">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Professor"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <td bgcolor="#fcc678">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Professor"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm dealing with these problems: First i want to sort the days of the week from monday to friday. I tried it with quite different ways but nothing seems to work.
After that I want to simply make the elements be in a table form but i want them to be sorted by day and coloured in groups. I can't color the groups(Day, Professor, Title, same color) but only the day column.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRT sorting, your code:

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="string-length(substringbefore('|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|',@Day))"/>
```

has two problems:

1. There is no `substringbefore()` function;
2. `Day` is an *element*, not an *attribute*.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="string-length(substring-before('|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|', Day))"/>
```

(Note that the `|` separator is redundant here.)

---

You should ask about the coloring separately. I will say this, though: there is no need to repeat the same code for every day of the week.

Comment: I m new to XML and really you helped me! Thank you, thank you, thank you. You rock!